# Cropping the Image Proportionally

Tags: javascript, php, image, crop

I'm trying to make a profile and cover picture selector. I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVatkCgU-Rg&t=44s) video. And integrated this system into my website. But there is a problem that I couldn't figure it out. Image is cropping by the selection area resolution. (For example, you are trying to make it responsive. And made the selection area resolution to 100x100 to fit the mobile screen. When apply it crops the image in 100x100 res.).

What I want is, the selection area should represent the desired image resolution but in a different size.
(For ex., I want a cropped image in 512x512. But in selection box it should be 100x100 or 200x200px for responsive website) How can I make it?

This is the selection area.

[image: selection area]

---

Here is index.php code;
[click](https://jsfiddle.net/9jr8xp6v/)

Here is upload.php

```html
<?php

//upload.php

if(isset($_POST["image"]))
{
 $data = $_POST["image"];

 $image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);

 $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);

 $data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);

 $imageName = time() . '.png';

 file_put_contents($imageName, $data);

 echo '<img src="'.$imageName.'" class="img-thumbnail" />';
}

?>
```

Here is croppie.js
[click](https://jsfiddle.net/5vh0srk2/)

Comment: Selection box??

Comment: The `result` Promise has a `size` option, and setting that to `"original"` will leave the image cropped but not resized. Which means if your selection box is a square, you will get a square image of arbitrary size, depending on the zoom level and original size. It could be a 77x77 image, or a 678x678 image. Resizing that to 512x512 (regardless of how sensible) is of course easily possible using [imagescale()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php)

Comment: @NalinNishant Sorry I forgot to describe. I added a picture of it.

Comment: @ChrisG But it always gives me the selection box sized pic. Regardless of the zoom level. The output is always 100x100.

Comment: I told you exactly how to prevent that; can you show us the JS code you wrote to set up croppie? (Put it in the question)

Comment: @ChrisG It's already in the question. In the index.php, bottom in <script> tag.

Comment: It's supposed to be inside the question, but I already found the respective option. Like I said already, you need `size: "original"` instead of `size: "viewport"`. Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/ramkh4y7/

Comment: @ChrisG Ohh I got it. Sorry about my lack of understanding :) Thank you so much for your answer. I appreciate you.